# How do I make a pyodbc script where I can update the database password if necessary

Tags: python, sql, passwords, pyodbc

I've created a Python script with pyodbc to access my server database. However, the password of the DB will eventually change and I would need an option to update it in the script.
So far I have

```
server = 'XXXXXXXX'
database = 'YYYYYYY'
username = 'ZZZZZZZZ'
password = 'ppp'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+password)
```

Should password 'ppp' change to say 'qqq', how can I add an option to update it and have the app replace the previous password?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an external resource to retrieve database credentials including a config .ini or .yaml file, environmental variables, or odbc.ini. Then, have this resource  update as needed and avoid hard-coding any values in script which otherwise pose security risks especially in productionizing your app:

**YAML Approach**

YAML

```
[DATABASE]
  server: 'XXXXXXXX'
  database: 'YYYYYYY'
  username: 'ZZZZZZZZ'
  password: 'ppp'
```

Python

```
import yaml
import pyodbc

with open("data.yaml", 'r') as stream:
    db_creds = yaml.load(stream)

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={{SQL Server}}; SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};' + \
                      'UID={username};PWD={password}'.format(**db_creds['DATABASE']))
```

---

**Environment Variable Approach**

Unix (`printenv`) or Windows (`SET` or `gci env`) *(command line output)*

```
...
DATABASE_SERVER='XXXXXXXX'
DATABASE_NAME='YYYYYYY'
DATABASE_USER='ZZZZZZZZ'
DATABASE_PWD='ppp'
...
```

Python

```
import os
import pyodbc

dbcreds = [os.environ['DATABASE_SERVER'], os.environ['DATABASE_NAME'],
           os.environ['DATABASE_USER'], os.environ['DATABASE_PWD'])

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={{SQL Server}}; SERVER={0};DATABASE={1};' + \
                      'UID={2};PWD={3}'.format(*db_creds))
```

---

**ODBC.ini Approach**

odbc.ini

```
[myDSN]
Driver = SQL Server
Database = 'YYYYYYY'
Servername = 'XXXXXXXX'
UserName = 'ZZZZZZZZ'
Password = 'ppp'
```

Python

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=myDSN')
```

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that some ODBC drivers ignore UID and PWD values in a DSN. IIRC, SQL Server ODBC drivers do that, at least on Linux.

Comment: Indeed @GordThompson. Alternative will then be to pass *UID* and *PWD* by a another config: `pyodbc.connect('DSN=myDSN;UID={0};PWD={1}'.format(*dbcreds))`.